Precise fractional years distance between two dates in Swift
I need to compute with precision the distance in years between two dates. Given the fact that all the years don't have the same amount of days, some have 366,  I can't count the days between the two days and divide by 365... Is there a straightforward method or more precise approach than:
import Foundation

func isLeapYear(_ year: Int) -> Bool {
    return (year % 4 == 0 && year % 100 != 0) || year % 400 == 0
}

func countLeapYears(_ startDate: Date, _ endDate: Date) -> (leapYears: Int, nonLeapYears: Int) {
    let calendar = Calendar.current
    
    let startYear = calendar.component(.year, from: startDate)
    let endYear = calendar.component(.year, from: endDate)
    
    var leapYears = 0
    var nonLeapYears = 0
    
    for year in startYear...endYear {
        if isLeapYear(year) {
            leapYears += 1
        } else {
            nonLeapYears += 1
        }
    }
    
    return (leapYears, nonLeapYears)
}

func yearsBetween(_ startDate: Date, _ endDate: Date) -> Double {
    let calendar = Calendar.current
    
    let totalSeconds = endDate.timeIntervalSince(startDate)
    
    let secondsInCommonYear = 365.0 * 24 * 60 * 60
    let secondsInLeapYear = 366.0 * 24 * 60 * 60
    
    let (leap, nonleap) = countLeapYears(startDate, endDate)
    let nominator = (Double(nonleap) * secondsInCommonYear + Double(leap) * secondsInLeapYear)
    let denominamtor = (nonleap + leap)
    let averageSecondsInYear = nominator / Double(denominamtor)
    
    let years = totalSeconds / averageSecondsInYear
    
    return years
}

let startDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .year, value: -46, to: .now)!
let endDate = Date.now
yearsBetween(startDate, endDate) // returns 46,00069901


You say "with precision" but don't define it.

An Interval of years with a decimal fraction (i.e. not days) will never be precise because of the leap years.

Here is how to do it in VBA (VB). You can probably easily convert that to Swift.
The method is to find the difference in years and then, for each date, to find the day of the year and divide that by the day count of the year, then calculate the total difference and round this to three decimals or less.
' Returns the decimal count of years between Date1 and Date2.
'
' Rounds by default to three decimals, as more decimals has no meaning
' because of the leap years.
' Optionally, don't round, by setting Round3 to False.
'
' 2017-01-24. Gustav Brock, Cactus Data ApS, CPH.
'
Public Function TotalYears( _
    ByVal Date1 As Date, _
    ByVal Date2 As Date, _
    Optional Round3 As Boolean = True) _
    As Double
    
    Dim Years       As Double
    Dim Part1       As Double
    Dim Part2       As Double
    Dim Fraction    As Double
    Dim Result      As Double
    
    Years = DateDiff(IntervalSetting(DtInterval.dtYear), Date1, Date2)
    Part1 = (DatePart(IntervalSetting(DtInterval.dtDayOfYear), Date1) - 1) / DaysInYear(Date1)
    Part2 = (DatePart(IntervalSetting(DtInterval.dtDayOfYear), Date2) - 1) / DaysInYear(Date2)
    
    If Round3 = True Then
        ' Round to three decimals.
        Fraction = (-Part1 + Part2) * 1000
        Result = Years + Int(Fraction + 0.5) / 1000
    Else
        Result = Years - Part1 + Part2
    End If
    
    TotalYears = Result
    
End Function

Source: VBA.Date
Your example:
StartDate = DateAdd("yyyy", -46, Now)
EndDate = Now

? TotalYears(StartDate, EndDate)
 46.002 


I would use a similar approach to what I did in this answer, where I calculate the fractional number of months.
The idea is to divide the Date range from start to end into 3 parts:

the part that is in the year of the start date
the part that is in the year of the end date
the integer number of years in between

Here is the code. Note that I force-unwrapped all the optionals to not clutter the calculations.
func secondsInYear(_ year: Int, era: Int, calendar: Calendar) -> TimeInterval {
    let startOfThisYear = calendar.date(from: .init(year: year))!
    let startOfNextYear = calendar.date(byAdding: .year, value: 1, to: startOfThisYear)!
    return startOfNextYear.timeIntervalSince(startOfThisYear)
}

func yearsBetween(_ start: Date, and end: Date, calendar: Calendar) -> Double {
    let startYearEra = calendar.dateComponents([.year, .era], from: start)
    let endYearEra = calendar.dateComponents([.year, .era], from: end)
    let startYearDuration = secondsInYear(startYearEra.year!, era: startYearEra.era!, calendar: calendar)
    let endYearDuration = secondsInYear(endYearEra.year!, era: endYearEra.era!, calendar: calendar)
    let startOfEndYear = calendar.date(from: startYearEra)!
    let endOfStartYear = calendar.date(byAdding: .year, value: 1, to: calendar.date(from: startYearEra)!)!
    if endOfStartYear < startOfEndYear { // start and end are in the same year
        return end.timeIntervalSince(start) / startYearDuration
    } else {
        let startFraction = endOfStartYear.timeIntervalSince(start) / startYearDuration
        let integerPart = calendar.dateComponents([.year], from: endOfStartYear, to: startOfEndYear).year!
        let endFraction = end.timeIntervalSince(startOfEndYear) / endYearDuration
        return startFraction + Double(integerPart) + endFraction
    }
}

